# How do you create user-restrictions using wireguard?

Tags: wireguard, openwrt

I have two modes that I like to use to model my desired vpn settings,

- device wireguards in has access only to jellyfin
- device wireguards in has access to all resources.

How do I configure OpenWRT for this? It seems the access rights it provides are for the entire vpn?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it’s feasible on OpenWRT+OpenVPN. (Even on Sophos UTM the same restriction is there, entire subnet allow. You can create firewall rule between the two zone but it’s a setup for everyone)

You would need a highter end router to allow more access control on your VPN users settings.

To state it in OpenVPN user acces-control I only see options to restrict what subnet the user can see. (https://openvpn.net/access-server-manual/user-management-user-permissions/)

Answer (score 0):

I no longer run openWRT on any of my devices; therefore couldn't test my answer. Please take care before adopting the config.

But since you did not mention this as a restriction, why not run two wireguard instances (you will need to have two listeners on different udp ports), and restrict incoming traffic from one of them?

The firewall rules would be along the lines of

```
config rule
option name 'Allow-wg0-jellyfin'
option src 'wg0'
option dest <jellyfin-zone>
option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
option name 'Disallow-wg0'
option src 'wg0'
option dest 'lan'
option target 'DROP'
```

I am also assuming that either your threat model does not include jellyfin users exploiting their access to hop from the jellyfin machine to the rest of your lan, or you already have sufficient isolation between them.